# Access MongoDB Rest Service to get a document inside a document

Tags: c#, rest, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

with mongodb and rest activated, i would like to query a document inside another document, what is the syntax ? In my exemple, I have a Person collection which contains an Order document for each Person.

Ex, I have this schema

```
public Person{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IList<Order> Order {get;set;}
}

public Order{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string OrderName {get;set;}
}
```

If I want to query the person with Id = 2, I just need to type this URL:

http://localhost:28017/MyDatabase/PersonCollection/?filter_Id=2

But what If I want to query the Order with Id = 40 ?

http://localhost:28017/MyDatabase/PersonCollection/?filter_Order.Id=40

But It doesn't work, it returns all the orders without my filter by Id=40.

What's the solution ?

Thanks
John

Comment: Can you show one Person document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax the same as usual, so following request should work:

```
http://localhost:28017/MyDatabase/PersonCollection/?filter_Order.Id=40
```

But yout document should looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "Order": [
    {
      "Id": 40,
      "OrderName": "name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: hi, yeah my Person document looks like exactly to what you wrote. And I try again your syntax, it still returns all orders instead of one order. :(

Comment: @JohnSmith: What in query field at http response? Also have you tried run same query from mongshell or some ui tool for mongodb (like mongovue for windows)? `filter_Order.Id` should work 100%, i am tested it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "query field at http response". I have MongoVue, the free version, I don't see I can paste my Http query into it ?

Here's how looks like my Person document inside mongoVue

{0} _id
Orders [4]
{0}{...}
_id
OrderName
{1}{...}
{2}{...}

Comment: Response should be like this: `{
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [

  ],

  "total_rows" : 0 ,
  "query" : { "Order.Id" : 40 } ,
  "millis" : 0
}` Here exists 'query' field.

Comment: Yeah thats it

  "total_rows" : 1 ,
  "query" : { "Order.Id" : "40" } ,
  "millis" : 0

Comment: You searching by `Order.Id` or by `Order.OrderName`? Since above query searching by OrderName of embedded Order collection and returns back one person that have Order with OrderName="40".

Comment: Here's the complete output of the http response:
 {
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [
    { 
      "Name" : "John Smith", 
      "Order" : 
      [ 
       { 
       "_id" : { "$binary" : "evbEXoL4E0qNgIpD6eZc1Q==", "$type" : "03" },
       "Id" : "10", 
       "OrderName" : "Foo", 
       }, 
       { "_id" : { "$binary" : "1JPq/XOyFUK1U2JVxFtoVQ==", "$type" : "03" }, 
       "Id" : "13", 
       "OrderName" : "Foo"
       }
      ], 
      "_id" : { "$binary" : "9psh4TsPckWTC9T9k48R+g==", "$type" : "03" } 
     }
    ],
 "total_rows" : 1 ,
 "query" : { "Order.Id" : "10" } ,
 "millis" : 0
}

Comment: yeah sorry, It was a mistake, I query by Id

Comment: the http url I type is as you said http://localhost:28017/MyDatabase/PersonCollection/?filter_Order.Id=40

Comment: @JohnSmith: All okay with response. `Order.Id` on mongodb language sounds like "Give me persons thats contains Order item with id = 10".

Comment: Yeah, it must be that. That explains why I can't extract a sub document from another document. thanks Andrew, you're the god of MongoDB